# SwiftUI Prevent Shapes From Expanding

Tags: swiftui

I have continually come across the issue where shapes take up any extra space even if I put a Spacer() inside of the same Stack. I was wondering if there was a fix for this. I have extensively looked for answers for this and in this instance, the blue rounded rectangles are causing the trouble. Please see the image below.

[image: Issue Image]

```swift
VStack{
    HStack(alignment: .top){
        VStack{
            Text("\(laRow.emNum).")
        }.padding(.trailing, 5)
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("\(laRow.emName)")
                .bold()
            HStack{
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(.blue)
                    Text("\(laRow.pos1)")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(1)
                }
                if(laRow.pos2 != ""){
                    ZStack{
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                            .fill(.blue)
                        Text("\(laRow.pos2)")
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .bold()
                            .padding(1)
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Text("\(laRow.emEmail)")
            if(laRow.emPhone != ""){
                Text("\(laRow.emPhone)")
            }
        }
        VStack{
            Menu{
                
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("View Profile")
                })
                Button(action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Send PIN")
                })
                Divider()
                Button(role: .destructive, action: {}, label: {
                    Text("Terminate Employee")
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                })
                
            }label: {
                
                ZStack{
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(Color(red: 80.0 / 255, green: 80.0 / 255, blue: 80.0 / 255))
                        .frame(width:50, height: 32)
                    Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                    
                }
            }
            
        }.padding(.leading, 5)
    }.padding()
    Line()
        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1, dash: [5]))
        .frame(height: 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors are greedy and fill all the space available to them. So if you want to put color behind another item, try using a background layer.

You are currently using a `ZStack` for the pos items:

```swift
ZStack{
    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
        .fill(.blue)
    Text("\(laRow.pos1)")
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .bold()
        .padding(1)
}
```

Try changing these to a simple `Text` field with background `Color` instead:

```swift
Text("\(laRow.pos1)")
    .foregroundStyle(.white)
    .bold()
    .padding(1)
    .background {
        Color.blue.cornerRadius(5)
    }
```

[image: Screenshot]

A background layer automatically adopts the size of the `View` it is applied to, so the `Color` doesn't bloat like it was doing when it was a standalone layer in the `ZStack`. The same goes for overlay layers too, by the way. However, beware that if you set the background using the version with round parenthesis instead of curly braces, then safe areas are ignored by default. In this case, if the `Color` is in contact with a screen edge then it will fill the safe area on that edge.